# Broke/Erase/Corrupt CD-R (Recordable)

Tags: optical

I have a CD-R (Recordable) optical disk, it has data, I know for sure this type of cd **can only be written once**. My question is, Is there any method so that the data in the cd is erased/broken/corrupted and the cd is no longer usable, **using the "burner"** and I mean the device with the laser that reads/writtes/burns the data into the cd?

My imagination says to me that if the data in the cd is actually sculpted by a laser and this data (don't take me wrong I don't know anything of how data is physically storaged in a disk) are 1s and 0s, it could be a chance so that the laser can write 0s or 1s in all the disk, therefore corrupting it???

This is just curiosity, asking if it is just possible in some way.

Comment: A second write violates your first assumption ("*I know for sure this type of cd can only be written once*"). In order for a second write to become possible you must change your assumptions.

Comment: @user535733 the thing is that I'm not trying to _"write"_ something that can be legible in some way later, I'm trying to corrupt it, unless there is some **hardware** limitation that restricts the laser from burning again a disk???

Comment: What you seem to be asking is "how do I trick the burner's firmware into mistaking a written CD-R for blank and allowing a another write?" This seems more hardware-related than Ubuntu-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to make the CD just a nice table coaster is throw it in the microwave for 15 seconds. Seems much easier than trying to trick your computer into writing over what was already there.

Not the answer you were looking for but an answer nonetheless.